# How to copy the text from editbox into a string array?

Tags: winapi, visual-studio-2012

I am making a win32 api window application project on visual studio 2012.I use a LPWSTR type variable to store my strings described as follow.

```
LPWSTR MyStringList[3]={L"apple",L"orange",L"watermelon"};
```

I expect to copy the text from an editbox to one of the strings in MyStringList. Therefore,I made a simple editbox and button.

Here is the definition of editbox and button.

```
case WM_CREATE:
    hEdit = CreateWindow(L"EDIT", 
            L"", 
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_AUTOHSCROLL, 
            10, 10, 200, 25, 
            hWnd, 
            (HMENU)ID_EDIT, 
            GetModuleHandle(NULL), 
            NULL);
    hBtn = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", 
            L"", 
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 
            250, 10, 50, 30, 
            hWnd, 
            (HMENU)ID_BUTTON, 
            GetModuleHandle(NULL), 
            NULL);
```

Here is the action when the button is pushed.The two messagebox are used to see if the string has been changed after function GetWindowText is called.

```
case WM_COMMAND:
    wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
    wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
    switch (wmId)
    {
    case ID_BUTTON:

        MessageBox(hWnd,MystringList[1],L"Before_Pusing",MB_OK);

        GetWindowText(hEdit,MystringList[1],sizeof(MystringList[1]));

        MessageBox(hWnd,MystringList[1],L"After_Pushing",MB_OK);

        InvalidateRect(hWnd,NULL,TRUE);
        break;
```

Now I tried to push the button after typing "banana" into the editbox. The second string "orange" should be replaced with "banana". However,it turned out that nothing changed .The second messagebox displayed "orange" as the first messagebox did. What's wrong with my code? Please help! Thanks a lot!

Comment: "orange" is a string literal and writing to it is UB. Try just a simple string copy to `MystringList[1]` and see what happens.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for your suggestion! I tried to declare `TCHAR NewItem = L"banana"; ` and added the command `MyStringList[1]=NewItem;`.It works fine, but

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for your suggestion! I tried to declare **`TCHAR *NewItem = L"banana"; `** and added the command `MyStringList[1]=NewItem;`.It worked fine, and "orange" successfully changed into "banana" . However, the problem became that "NewItem" didn't change when I called `GetWindowText(hEdit,NewItem,sizeof(NewItem));`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff Thanks for your help! however, I tried `GetWindowText(GetDlgItem(hWnd,ID_EDIT),MyStringList[1],sizeof(MyStringList[1]));` but the result was the same as `GetWindowText(hEdit,MyStringList[1],sizeof(MyStringList[1]));` It seems that the text in the second messagebox didn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this, adding whatever programming quirks that Windows needs.

```
#define MYLEN 20
...
char MyStringList[3][MYLEN+1] = {"apple", "orange", "watermelon"};
```

Then you can fetch the string from the edit box with

```
GetWindowText(hEdit,MystringList[1],MYLEN);
```

Although the `GetWindowText()` documentation says

*"Copies the text of the specified window's title bar (if it has one) into a buffer. If the specified window is a control, the text of the control is copied. However, `GetWindowText` cannot retrieve the text of a control in another application."*

Comment: Thanks for your complete tutorial! Although there was an compiling error :  `error C2664: 'MessageBoxW' : can't turn parameter 2 from 'char [3][21]' into 'LPCWSTR'`,I tried to declare 
` **TCHAR** MyStringList[3][MYLEN+1] = {"apple", "orange", "watermelon"}; ` and it worked pretty fine ! Thanks a lot for your help :)